# Implement “intersection” method using java

Tags: java, methods, intersection

How can i implement “intersection” method  using java by recieve 2 integer parameters and return integer intersection point.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem at hand? what are the types of input? what do you mean by intersection point? this is not clear.

Comment: Intersection of lines maybe?  How would you do that using regular math?  Use the same formulas and write a function to return the corresponding values.

Comment: -1 @ Giffary you really need more information as you can see from the bunch of questions and guesses about what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22777/how-to-find-a-closest-integer-point-to-intersection-of-two-lines) could help

Comment: If that's what he means, I'll eat my hat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean *bitwise intersection*, in which case you are looking for the *bitwise-and operator* (`&`). If so, you use it like this:

```
int x = int1 & int2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a function that takes two 'line' objects and returns a coordinate where they intersect, i suggest looking at the formula here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection

and doing

```
func(line a, lineb)
{
  x1 = a.coord1.x;
  y1 = a.coord1.y;
  x2 = a.coord2.x;
  y2 = a.coord2.y;
  //do math and code here
  return line(coord(x1new,y1new),coord(x2new,y2new));
}
```

If this isn't what you wanted, please refer to Ido's comment :p

Comment: He said the input was an integer ?!

Comment: hmm, indeed ...I took a leap of mind reading ...since i find it hard to believe that you can have an intersection with only two integers :p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really lazy why don't you just use the line2d library.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html  It can find the intersect and many other things that have to do with a 2d line already built in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, if you use two integer parameters, all you really need to do is average the two numbers, and that's the midpoint (intersection, I guess?)

```
int intersect(int a, int b) {
    return ((a + b) / 2);
}
```

Otherwise, if you are looking for bitwise intersection, you would used the bitwise-AND operator - &.  Here's an example:

```
int intersect(int a, int b) {
    return (a & b);
}
```